# "Minore" e "inferiore": qual è la differenza?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Buongiorno a tutti,
sapete dirmi la differenza tra "minore" e "inferiore"?

Esempio: 
"Quest'anno il numero di studenti è stato ***minore/inferiore*** a quello del 2015".

Quando usare uno e quando l'altro?

Grazie mille.

Comment: Grosso modo *minore* significa *più piccolo*, *inferiore* significa *più basso*. Quando si parla di numeri sono più o meno interscambiabili, non così per altri contesti (e.g. *I piani inferiori* non *I piani minori*).

Answer (score 7):

Come commenta Denis, sono i gradi comparativi di due aggettivi diversi.

- "Minore" è il comparativo di "piccolo" (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/minore/).
- "Inferiore" è il comparativo di "ìnfero", aggettivo poco usato che significa "basso" nell'accezione di "posto in basso" (piuttosto che "di bassa statura"). (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/inferiore/)

Possiamo in questo modo spiegare gli esempi che cita Denis:

- Per i numeri si usano (metaforicamente) entrambi gli aggettivi (si può dire sia un numero "piccolo" che un numero "basso"), per cui si possono usare entrambi i comparativi. Questo giustifica l'esempio proposto dall'OP.
- "Piano inferiore" è corretto, ma "piano minore" no, perché dei piani di un edificio ha senso dire se sono alti o bassi, ma non se sono grandi o piccoli (oddio, in alcuni casi può anche aver senso parlare della dimensione, ma non è quello che normalmente si indente).
- "Figlio minore" è corretto, ma "figlio inferiore" no, perché dei figli ha senso dire se sono grandi o piccoli, ma non se sono posti in alto o in basso (di nuovo, faccio riferimento all'uso più comune).